# Check if username exists, if so, increment by one

Tags: php, mysql, increment

When a username is inserted into my database, such as:

- John_Smith

I need to check if there is already a John_Smith present. If so, increment it by 1 to become John_Smith_1

So if the following usernames already exist:

- John_Smith
- John_Smith_1
- John_Smith_2
- John_Smith_3
- ....up to John_Smith_10

I need the next John_Smith inserted to be incremented to John_Smith_11.

So far, I have searched and come up with this:

```
  $preferredname= "John_Smith"

        //check for duplicate user names
        $duplicate= check_for_duplicate_username($preferredname);                       

        //if duplicate, increment the preferredname     
        if ($duplicate) 
        {
          $parts = explode("_",$preferredname);

          if (isset($parts[1]))
          $preferredname = $parts[0]."_".$parts[1]."_".($parts[2]+1);

          else $preferredname = $parts[0]."_".$parts[1]."_1";
        }
```

This, I believe would work for only the first matching usernames. My problem is checking the database for the version of the name with the highest number.. This is my sql:

```
        function check_for_duplicate_username($name)
{
     // check if username already exists
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_username=$name";
    //then return duplicates
```

Comment: You have a XY problem here. Your ddls should change, you are mis-using your database

Comment: I hate it when web sites do that. Just tell the user that name is taken and let them choose another.

Comment: Quick thoughts - Maybe you should save the incremented value along with the user so you can sort by that column. Or, you can perhaps append the ID to the username if it's taken. Or better yet, return an "error" stating the username is taken and have them choose another name.

Comment: Thanks yall, although I failed to mention that the users login with social networks, so usernames are generated automatically depending on their social logins...i suppose I could use their email as the username, but that may not be welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this may not be the best solution in the grand scheme of things, here is an answer that addresses what you were specifically trying to do. The following query returns the number of users with either $name or $name_123 `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE user_username REGEXP '$name[_0-9]*$';` So if the value is `0` you can simply use `$name` by itself, otherwise you can use `$name."_".` + the number returned by the query.

But as many people have mentioned, prly not the best idea to autoassign usernames (very web 1.0 :P ). I'd recommend email addresses. Another option is to use whatever userid the social app uses along with another field identifying the social app (if you have multiple), and then using an autoincremented id field as the unique primary key..

Comment: yea I think this is the best way to go. I will something unique from their profile, and add a display name field to show something friendly in the UI. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_username LIKE ' . $name . '_%';
```

the above will query for rows in which user_username have value similar to John_Smith_* ( where * is any valid character including number, which you have to check later )

you can use this php statement for getting user's suffix number:

```
preg_match( '/([0-9]+)$/', 'John_smith_10', $matches );
$user_number = $matches[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem I was trying to solve today and did it like this. In my case I needed to store/create a unique directory name based on the users first initial/last name:

```
$username = "bjones";
$usersql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE '$username%'";
$usercnt = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con,$usersql));  

// If bjones, bjones1, bjones2, etc already exists
if ($usercnt >= 1) {
    $num = ++$usercnt;             // Increment $usercnt by 1
    $username = $username . $num;  // Add number to username
}
```

Assuming bjones, bjones1, bjones2 already exists, I would end up with bjones3.

Comment: And what if bjones, bjones1 and bjones3 exist? (no bjones2)